# How to divide a text box into parts so that each part accepts one letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsp

I have to design a registration form[image: which looks like the following image]

I have to create a textbox and divide it into multiple parts with each part accepting only one character as we can see in the image.

I have no idea how to divide a textbox as later I also need to populate certain fields from the database. Could you please tell me a solution to divide a text box into parts to enter one character in each part.

Comment: You need a jQuery Mask plugin like http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ and http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/input-format

Comment: I saw this example but I want seperate text boxes for each character

Comment: You want to transform a paper based form to an e-form... but u want to make it look exactly the same? These paper forms where designed 100 years ago and need to be burned quickly... I mean, you need 15 digits for a Postcode? Just give a max length to your inputs, make the look nice and modern with css, put all the required validation there and it will look perfect with good user experience as well...

Comment: @Thanos could you please suggest me a sample code

Comment: Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/2rN7u/1/

Comment: @Thanos but here in your example the text box is not divided, it is a single text box

Comment: If you make this type of divided input boxes, it will take lot of effort during processing.
eg: to get name of organisation you have to concatenate all these single boxes value

Comment: But that is the requirement , I have to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" />
```

try to add property maxlength

---

I created a php sample for your reference

http://pastebin.com/uj2jywKz

Comment: you are suggesting to write hundreds of input tags?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @speeday125, is there any other efficient way of doing it?

Comment: user2077648 , I created a php sample for your reference

http://pastebin.com/uj2jywKz

Comment: There is no other way I think unless there is a plugin for this.

Comment: @Parfait could you please explain your code I dont understand php

Answer (score 0):

If this is just **one** form and the customer wants to have exact same form, then build it with `<input type="text" maxlength="1" />`. You can write some JSP tags which generates all these `<input type="text" maxlength="1" />` for you.

```
<mytag:generate size="12">
```

On the other hand you could use the mask property and change your mask to `mask('0|0|0|0|0|0|0')`, Then by adjusting the size of input text, font size, and making the mask visible you can mimic the above form. Please note that if you change the color of mask same as background color, then the form looks better too.

Answer (score 0):

What is the real value of producing a form like this in HTML? As far as I can tell forms like this one are made so computer programs can rapidly identify incomplete or incorrect fillings and/or to allow visual inspection of those filled manually.

If the real need here is to produce a form like this out of input values I believe the right design would be to provide a regular form input element and later on process the submission building the expected format.

Separation of concerns is important. In this case forcing a user to type character-tab-character would become a bad experience that would force the developer to put javascript code just to make sure once a letter is typed the cursor can go to the next spot. Not need to mention what editions would look like.

There is a reason why a component like this has not been built so far. The reason is poor UI/UX.

Hope it would help with your decision.

Answer (score 0):

I Think, you need to create seperate input tag for each letter since we cannot splitup a single input tag